# 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute<TElement>(System.Uri)' cannot be inferred from the usage

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to update the `statecode` of a record in CRM 2011. But getting the following error while building the project.

**Error**

> Error 1   The type arguments for method 
>   'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute(System.Uri)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

**Code**

```
var setStateReq = new SetStateRequest
{
    EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("new_entityname", 
            entityname.new_entitynameid),
            State = new OptionSetValue(1),
            Status = new OptionSetValue(2),
};
_context.Execute(setStateReq);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this using `OrganizationServiceProxy` rather than Context

```
using (var proxy = ProxyHelper.GetOrganizationServiceProxy())
{
    var setStateReq = new SetStateRequest
    {
        EntityMoniker = new EntityReference("new_entityname", 
        entityname.new_entitynameid),
        State = new OptionSetValue(1),
        Status = new OptionSetValue(2),
    };

    proxy.Execute(setStateReq);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that the `Execute<T>` `T` generic argument method cannot be inferred *as is*.

You need to provide some type to the `T` generic parameter explicitly:

```
_context.Execute<SomeType>(setStateReq);
```

Comment: thanks. I have no idea what `SomeType` can be. I have tried entity name but does not work.

Comment: @Scorpion What's the name of the `T` parameter in your actual code?